# How can I calculate the layout size for a view whose layout respects the safe area?

Tags: ios

I can instantiate a view and calculate the height that would be required to lay it out with a given available width, using the following logic:

```
let view = MyView()
view.apply(viewModel)
let size = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: 0),
                                        withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
                                        verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)
```

`size.height` is the height required to lay out this view, but since it's not part of a view hierarchy `safeAreaInsets` will always be zero.  I would like to know the height required to lay out this same view for a given safe area insets value.  Is that possible?

Comment: Of course if I know that all the subviews in MyView are laid out within the safe area, I can just reduce `availableWidth` by the left and right safe area insets.  But for a more complex layout that could yield the wrong answer.

Comment: Is this for educational purposes? or you actually have a case?

Comment: If your view going to have leading/trailing constraint to safe area. then just subtract it as you said. if not then don't.
Are you not adding leading and trailing constraints? You should.

Comment: @hasan educational, but it's not hard to think of a realistic case.  Let's say there's a subview that's laid out at least 10pts from the leading and trailing edges, and always within the safe area.  The simple method of subtracting the safe area horizontal insets would fail in that case.

Comment: I'm aware that that use case could be solved by subtracting `max(0, insets.left + insets.right - 20)` from the width, but you can see how this solution is getting increasingly fragile.  I'm looking to see if a robust solution exists.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand you. maybe you confused me mentioning the safe area. Don't know. Is there a reason why you don't want to add constraint? wether to safe area or just edges?

Comment: I mean you can always connect the constraint to an outlet and subtract their constant values from the width. I always do that.

Comment: I still not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Does my suggestion answers you? shall I add an answer?